# Failed to start NameNode

Tags: java, hadoop

I've successfully installed hadoop on local by following these steps [Step by step hadoop installation on windows 10](https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/Step-by-step-Hadoop-2.8.0-installation-on-Window-10)

Java installed version: 1.8.0_231
Hadoop installed version: Hadoop 3.2.1

But after running command `hdfs namenode -format` I'm getting following error

```
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory root= C:\hadoop-3.2.1\data\namenode; location= null ? (Y or N) y
2019-10-19 12:34:58,809 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-1445655329-172.18.148.177-1571468698797
2019-10-19 12:34:58,809 INFO common.Storage: Will remove files: []
2019-10-19 12:34:58,812 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Files.java:2044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:613)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1759)
2019-10-19 12:34:58,819 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
2019-10-19 12:34:58,823 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at CWT-DST-0051/***.**.***.***
```

I'm totally new to this, what can be the issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the issue by installing Hadoop 2.9.1, there was namenode issue in Hadoop 3.2.1 version
[hdfs namenode issue in 3.2.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-14890)

Answer (score 3):

1. If you have installed **32-bit** Java version in your windows, uou have to set environtment variables `JAVA_HOME` path set as `C:\Progra~2\Java\<JDK version>` but it seems to not working.

- Therefor you have to try **64-bit** java version by setting you `JAVA_HOME` as `C:\Progra~1\Java\<JDK version>`.

After setting 64-bit Java version as `JAVA_HOME` you have to run `start-all.cmd` again in `cmd`. Then except `namenode`, all other deamons were worked. To run `namenode` you have to follow these steps.

1. Open **cmd** as **administrator.**
2. Type and run `stop-all.cmd`
3. Then run `hadoop namenode –format`
4. Finally run `start-all.cmd`

Hope it will work for you.

**Edit-:**

Go to your config files of hdfs with following codes (enter it in cmd or powershell)

vim %HADOOP_HOME%\etc\hadoop\hdfs-site.xml

In your config files, you need to use forward slashes and a protocol for the file URI

For example, change

```
 C:\BigData\hadoop-2.9.1\data\namenode
```

to

```
file:/C:/BigData/hadoop-2.9.1/data/namenode
```

Comment: I've installed 64-bit java version 1.8.0_231 and tried setting  `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin` & `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_231` and followed your steps to format namenode, still I'm getting same error ` Failed to start namenode. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: follow this tutorial https://exitcondition.com/install-hadoop-windows/. After that if you get same error then try my answer which is given above

Comment: Followed this tutorial and your steps, still same error

Comment: I have upgraded my answer can you refer that

Comment: I resolved the issue by installing Hadoop 2.6.0, there was namenode issue in Hadoop 3.2.1 version

Comment: Now I'm trying again with 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time trying to help here, I just found a solution to this. I am using the Hadoop version 3.2.1, and it still works. All you have to do is to download the hadoop-hdfs-3.2.1.jar file from this link "https://github.com/FahaoTang/big-data/blob/master/hadoop-hdfs-3.2.1.jar", and then go to your "hadoop-3.2.1\share\hadoop\hdfs" directory, delete the "hadoop-hdfs-3.2.1.jar file and replace it with the one you downloaded. Hope it helps!